# How do you get a pager in svn diff?

Tags: svn, diff

I’d like `svn diff` to display colored diff through a pager (just like git does). I’ve succeeded to get a colored diff by setting the `diff-cmd` in `~/.subversion/config`:

```
diff-cmd = colordiff
```

Now I’d like to pipe the diff output through a pager, how do I do that? (Short of writing `svn diff | less`, of course.)

Comment: [Good answer here](http://superuser.com/a/241833/197866) (different `less` options to one below).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the past I've used a wrapper script and set `diff-cmd` to this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
colordiff "$@" | less -r
```

But then you get a separate pager for every file, I'm not sure if this is what you want. Nowadays I just write `svn diff | less`.

Another easy solution is making an alias: `alias svndiff='svn diff | less'`. Or if you want to use `svn diff`, make a shell function:

```
svn() {
    if [ x"$1" = xdiff ] || [ x"$1" = xdi ]; then
        /usr/bin/svn "$@" | less -r
    else
        /usr/bin/svn "$@"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually run `svn diff | vim -`.

Comment: Original answer used `vimdiff` but this isn't any more useful that `vim` and shows an annoying fold bar on the left of the screen.

Comment: @AlastairIrvine The question asks specifically for a coloured diff pager. Vim standalone doesn't do that. Vimdiff shows side-by-side diff which is very useful.

Comment: Vimdiff doesn't do anything special in this case, like I said.  For Vimdiff to work it needs two files.

Comment: Fair enough @AlastairIrvine

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
function sdi ()
{
    if tty -s; then
            exec svn diff --diff-cmd=colordiff "$@" | less -R
    else
            exec svn diff --diff-cmd=colordiff "$@"
    fi
}
```

to my `~/.bashrc` did the trick for me. Taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/qerub/961803#file-svn-diff-color-sh)

Answer (score 0):

This would've been a comment, but I don't have enough rep. An improvement on schot's answer is to also fail before piping to `less` if the `svn` command fails for any reason, for example if you specify a file that doesn't exist. It also passes through the error code as well.

And this answer also adds progress format:

**EDIT: An additional approvement is when piping/redirecting output to not use colordiff. To do this, do not change `~/.subversion/config` and instead we need to use the `--diff-cmd` option.**

```
function svn() {
    if [[ "$1" == "diff" && -t 1 ]]; then
        output=$(/usr/bin/svn --diff-cmd=colordiff "$@") || return $?
        [ "${output}" != "" ] && less -rM +Gg <<< "${output}";
    else
        /usr/bin/svn "$@"
    fi
}
```